# How do I set up ExoPlayer in a Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, exoplayer

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use ExoPlayer when in a fragment.  It appears like the video player is set up, but nothing happens when I click play.

My guess is that it has something to do with context, but I'm not sure.

```
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.example.devtrainingapp.databinding.FragmentVideoBinding
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.DashMediaSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource

class FragmentVideo : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentVideoBinding
    // on below line we are creating a variable for our exo player view
    private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
    private var playbackPosition = 0L
    private var playWhenReady = true


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentVideoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        preparePlayer()
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun preparePlayer() {
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(requireActivity().applicationContext).build()
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
        binding.idExoPlayerView.player = exoPlayer
        val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(URL)
        val mediaSource =
            DashMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
        exoPlayer?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer?.seekTo(playbackPosition)
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
        exoPlayer?.prepare()
    }

    private fun releasePlayer() {
        exoPlayer?.let { player ->
            playbackPosition = player.currentPosition
            playWhenReady = player.playWhenReady
            player.release()
            exoPlayer = null
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        releasePlayer()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        releasePlayer()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        releasePlayer()
    }

    companion object {
        const val URL = "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20201217163353/Screenrecorder-2020-12-17-16-32-03-350.mp4"
    }

}
```

I tried switching the URL and changing how the context was received, but it didn't result in anything.